# Caption is not centered in pgflots

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

My caption is not centered under the two subfigures. Compile able code and data file is attached. Kindly help

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.1\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Requests,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.2,0.5)},anchor=north},
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.365,0.216)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0.2, ymax=0.6, ytick={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6},
    xmin=0, xmax=1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]{a.txt};
\legend{Proactive high load, Proactive low load, Reactive low load, Reactive high load}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\hspace{5.8cm}
 \begin{subfigure}{.1\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=Satisfied Requests,
    xlabel=Cache size,
    height=5cm, width=8cm,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.2,0.5)},anchor=north},
    legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1, legend style={inner xsep=2pt, inner ysep=2pt,at={(0.996,0.21)},anchor=east,font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend columns=1,
    xticklabel style={anchor=near xticklabel},
    ymin=0, ymax=1, ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
    xmin=0, xmax=1, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
]
\addplot [thick,mark size=1.8pt,mark=square,red] table[x=x, y=y]{a.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{0.3cm}
\caption{Simulation results for Proactive vs. Reactive caching with low and high load.}
\label{LQI-timex}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
x   y
0.1 0.53896
0.2 0.52122
0.3 0.50326
0.4 0.48145
0.5 0.45054
0.6 0.42319
0.7 0.40357
0.8 0.38396
0.9 0.36315
1   0.34668
```

Comment: you have put the figure back in a `center` environment, as told in comments earlier today that is wrong,  also why have you put `\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi` back (it does nothing at all) and  why put `[pdftex]` in `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}` which was removed in the last answer? if you are using pdftex it is just unneeded, but if you are using xetex (as you have tagged the question) it is wrong

Comment: you have made your subfigures just `\begin{subfigure}{.1\linewidth}` which is not wide enough to fit the plots or the captions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but even after following them i am unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: David so what would you suggest to put along the linewidth?

Comment: `IEEEtran` uses a two-column layout, `figure` spans just one column. Use `figure*` instead,

Comment: If you used the code in the answer and comments to the question you just asked then you would not have the issue you have here. Since you just started again with the exact same errors as the previous question then the images of course do not fit.  use `figure*` as explained previously